# Spring Cloud Data Flow Custom Task Execution always in UNKNOWN state

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I'm using the local Spring Cloud Data Flow server 1.6.0.RELEASE. When I create a new simple task definition that consists solely of the built-in `timestamp` task and execute it the task is properly executed and the status is marked as `COMPLETE`. Now I want to create my own application and use it in a task. So I created a template with the Spring Initializr with Spring Boot 2.0.4 and the cloud task dependency and customized the task as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTask
public class TaskProductSearchApplication {

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return new HelloWorldCommandLineRunner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskProductSearchApplication.class, args);
    }

    public static class HelloWorldCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a new task within the Data Flow server with my custom application and execute it, the task prints `"Hello, World!"` and exits successfully, but the status of the definition is always `UNKNOWN`. I expect it to be `COMPLETE`.

I see entries for the `timestamp` and `Hello world` executions in my `task_execution` table but there are only entries for the `timestamp` execution in the `task_execution_params` table.

Comment: Task Executions don't have a status...do you mean the status of the definition?

Comment: @MichaelMinella yes of course

Comment: Which version are you using (CloudFoundry, Kubernetes, or Local)?

Comment: @MichaelMinella local

Comment: @user6845507  I pulled down the 1.6.0.RELEASE of SCDF and created a task 2.0 app using the code you provided and it worked for me against a mysql database.   
What database are you using?
Also can you share a github repo with the sample project that you are working on?

Comment: I'm using a postgres database defined in my docker-compose.yml. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/lahr/886109d5c712be60ae03e9d3206e26fb). Basically the [template from the quickstart](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/v1.6.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/docker-compose.yml) with an additional postgres service instead of H2.